# Signed long integer becomes negative as it grows?

Tags: c

I'm doing some math, then printing a signed long integer like so:

**file1.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    long my_signed_integer = 9999L * 9999L * 9999L * 9999L;
    printf("This is my signed integer %ld.\n", my_signed_integer); 

    return 0;
}
```

**Makefile**

```
CFLAGS=-Wall -g

all: file1

clean:
    rm -f file1
```

I was trying to see how far I could go without my compiler throwing me an error, adding one more `9999L` to the multiplication each time, then running:

```
make
./file1.c
```

To see what happens.

---

**4 Times**

When using `9999L` 4 times (like in the example above), I get:

`This is my signed integer 9996000599960001.`

Without any warning.

---

**5 Times**

Using `9999L` 5 times, I get 1 warning:

```
warning: overflow in expression; result is 7716289630452291919 with type 'long'
      [-Winteger-overflow]
```

But the file still compiles, and the eventual result is:

`This is my signed integer 7716289630452291919.`

---

**6 Times**

Using `9999L` 6 times, I get 2 warnings - one with a negative number:

```
warning: overflow in expression; result is 7716289630452291919 with type 'long'
      [-Winteger-overflow]
        long my_signed_integer = 9999L * 9999L * 9999L * 9999L * 9999L * 9999L;
                                                               ^
warning: overflow in expression; result is -7550445434587511647 with type 'long'
      [-Winteger-overflow]
        long my_signed_integer = 9999L * 9999L * 9999L * 9999L * 9999L * 9999L;
```

Alas, the files still compiles, and the result is:

`This is my signed integer -7550445434587511647.`

---

And this pattern continues as I add more and more integers - I get another warning every time.

First, can someone explain why doesn't the compiler just crash and refuse to compile the file? There's obviously an overflow - why is this tolerated, and other cases - such as multiplying very large numbers - crash it?

Also, why is the eventual result a negative integer?

Comment: Signed integer overflow is undefined behaviour, or in other words "behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data, for which this International Standard imposes no requirements". So a compiler is free to refuse to compile, may issue a warning, or may do what ever it pleases, for example compile a program that formats your hard drive (unlikely). With `-Werror` you'd get an error instead of a warning in this case.

Comment: To extend what @IljaEverilä wrote: There is no requirement for the implementation to document how it hebaves, nor to generate the same behaviour for different such parts of the code. That means inspecing **what** specifically happens is useless. You have to fix the cause.

Comment: As to why overflow results in a negative number in this particular case, your system probably uses [2's complement representation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), but as @Olaf pointed out you cannot rely on that happening.

Comment: @Olaf I think I understand, but from a more modernly-trained programmer's perspective this seems odd. In a program as simple as this, how do I track the cause? Or was this rhetorical and I should not attempt to decipher what exactly my clang compiler is doing?

Comment: @IljaEverilä So you're telling me you think 2's complement repr. is the reason, but there is no way to actually see that this is the reason I'm getting a negative integer?

Comment: If by "modernly" you mean "not learned the basics", you are right. The word "**undefined**" tells all. And that is not a matter of 2's complement. Just write your code correctly so it does not invoke UB.

Comment: @Olaf got me there. Thanks!

Comment: Just a side question: how in the wide wide world of sports does that makefile work?

Comment: @KevinDTimm If you could elaborate on exactly what I got wrong I'd be happy. I use a book to learn C (Zed Shaw's LCTHW) and this is almost an identical copy of the Makefile he teaches in the first exercises.

Comment: Must be a variant I'm not familiar with as my `make` considers that the target here is `file1.c` and so compiles nothing (it certainly doesn't make an executable)

Comment: @KevinDTimm Sorry about that, I typed it by hand and didn't copy-paste - edited it to remove the `.c`. :)

Comment: Under no circumstances should you type this information in when you can copy/paste specifically for this reason.

Comment: Just keep in mind that Zed's books tend to gather a lot of [criticism](https://www.google.fi/search?q=learn+c+the+hard+way+criticism).

Comment: @IljaEverilä As I'm partial to Zed's side of things (he won me over in [this talk](https://vimeo.com/53494258) I feel obligated to mention he wrote a [detailed blog post](https://zedshaw.com/2015/09/28/taking-down-tim-hentenaar/) in direct reference to the first link in the google search results. Although, to be fair - he is controversial.  As per the copy/paste thing - the Makefile had originally quite a few files it was building, so I hand-wrote only the one in question, and forgot to drop the extension.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Overflow of signed integer types is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as per the C standard.  So the compiler is free to generate whatever behavior it wishes.  This also means it is free to generate a warning or not.

In practice, on an hosted implementation using 2's complement representation for integers, an overflow will behave as though the arguments are unsigned (and therefore an reduced modulo 2^(bit-length)) and the result interpreted as signed.

In your particular case it seems that `long` is a 64-bit type.  So multiplying `9999L` by itself 4 times fits within that type, but any more and you have overflow.  The values you're getting are the lowest 64 bits of the result interpreted as a `signed long`.

In the case of 5 times, the high order bit happens to not be set, so the result displays at positive.  In the case  of 6 times, the high order bit is set, so it displays as negative.

Comment: Modern compilers can and will exploit UB to any degree. There is no guarantee for unsigned-like wrap around for every expression (although it is likely for a simple addition on **general purpose CPUs** like x86 and ARM). For constant expressions, the compiler could generate quite crude code, though, as it know the UB at run-time.